# Better way to convert string to integer

Tags: c

I wrote this code to read a variable in a .txt file, ignore the first character and convert into a integer.It works but looks dumb, is there a better way to do this? I'm using just one string here but it's supposed to work with four.

```
void read(char a[])
{
    int i;
    char a1[3];
    for (i = 0; i<3; ++i){
        a1[i]= a[i+1];
    }

    int b1 = atoi(a1);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen( "file.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf( "Arquivo nao encontrado\n");
    }

    char a[4];
    fscanf(file, "%s\n",&a);

    read(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are just ignoring the first character, can't you just say `atoi(a+1)`?

Comment: @alvits i tried and it didn't worked, but thanks.

Comment: It certainly does work. You must have done it wrongly.

Comment: @EJP: it works, with the caveat that if the input is 4 characters, `char a[4];` isn't big enough, and the copied string in the function is not null terminated, and so on.  If the array size is increased and the call to `atoi(a+1)` is made in `main()`, then it works.  Of course, it would also help if the code printed out the converted value somewhere, rather than blithely discarding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "file.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int value;

    if (fscanf(fp, "%*c%d", &value) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read integer value from file %s\n", filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Read %d\n", value);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The `%*c` reads a single character but does not assign it.  The `*` to suppress an assignment is a general mechanism in the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
family of functions.

<sup>*Untested code.*</sup>